# Как нагрузить оперативную память в c++

Tags: c++

Пытался так

```
while (true)
{
    new int[16];
}
```

но через какое-то время программа вылетает

в гугле ответ не нашёл

Comment: Не понял. Разумеется, через некоторое время программа вылетит - "память" закончится. К "нагрузке оперативной памяти" на традиционной современной платформе типа Windows/Linux это, правда, никакого отношения не имеет.

Comment: Что в вашем понимании означает "нагрузить память"?

Comment: Думаю, автору вопроса надо просто создать массив сразу большой (размер -это уже подбирать надо) и просто писать туда к примеру 0x55 / 0xAA и проверять, то ли читается.

Comment: Вас исключение из цикла выкидывает. Попробуйте `new (std::nothrow) int[16];`